# How to call a function inside a scriptcontrol from outside using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I look it up for a while but couldn't find the answers I'm looking for.

I'm create an new TextBox from scratch using the IScriptControl and ScriptManager.

everything works fine inside my scriptcontrol but I'm wondering how I can trigger a function inside the scriptcontrol from outside.

to give an example. Lets say I have this:

```
    Type.registerNamespace('QuyoDevLib.Web.UI');
    QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox = function (element) {
        QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox.initializeBase(this, [element]);
        this._element = this.get_element();

    }
    QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox.prototype = {
        initialize: function () {
            QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

        },
        dispose: function () {

            QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
        },
        doSomething: function() {
        //do something usefull
        }
    }
    QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox.registerClass('QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox', Sys.UI.Control);
    if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined')
        Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

```
    $create(QuyoDevLib.Web.UI.InputBox, null, null, null, $get("TestControl"))
```

How can I make this underlaying javascript work to trigger the "doSomething" function inside my scriptcontrol?
What I had in mind you see under here but this doesn't work I already tested it.

```
    <script>
    function test() {
       $get("TestControl").doSomething();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k I looked a bit more and found my own solution.

I share it here so everyone with the same question or problem can use it.

I had to change $get into $find to make it work.

```
     <script>
        function test() {
           $get("TestControl").doSomething();
        }
        </script>
```